# How to count the rows by created date in Laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am trying to count the rows by created_at like

```
Created_at                        COUNT(*)
----------------------------------- ----------
2017-08-13                                    5
2017-08-12                                    6
2017-08-11                                    7
2017-07-10                                    8
2017-07-19                                    1
```

So I can show the client like in 2017-07-10, there are 8 people signed up. In 2017-08-13, there are 5 people signed up or something like that.

Here is what I tried,

```
$count=DB::table('jobseekers')->select('created_at')->groupBy('created_at')->count();
    // return $count;
    dd($count);
```

but this is just showing only the number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$count = DB::table('jobseekers')
             ->select('created_at', DB::raw('count(*) as peoples'))
             ->groupBy('created_at')
             ->get();
```

Comment: Hi how to union the other tables using this concept? Can you show me the tips? thanks dude

Comment: @ThanHtutOo I don't see any other tables? Could you please make another question and state there explicitly which are the tables you want to perform a union, with a sample input and a sample output? This way it would be helpful for others also. Thanks !