# How to count two related dates in Laravel using Query Builder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this list of dates

[image]

I want to count the times that the time is higher than 24 hours between each dates in a row... tried with this ..

```
$tiempo1  = DB::table('incidencia_tiempo')
            ->whereTime('time', '>', '0000-00-00 24:00:00')
            ->count();
```

Beetween time and created at... I would like to count... if beetween the two times the hours are higher than 24 hours then add +1 to the count

I have to make a comparation with created_at and time and I don't know how

Comment: this question has already answered here please check :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45902312/how-to-count-the-rows-by-created-date-in-laravel-query-builder

Comment: yes, but that's only for count... I want to make a comparation beetween the two times

Comment: Okay @Oscar , Please ask exact question- your questions is - How to count dates in Laravel using Query Builder?

Comment: my bad... I edited the title.. I want to know how could I make a comparation between two differents dates... then make the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` to get the time between two datetime,

If you want to count the `time` high than the `created_at` 24 hours

```php
$count  = DB::table('incidencia_tiempo')
            ->where(DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time, created_at)'), '>', 24)
            ->count();
```

if you want to count the time difference between two datetimes high than 24 hours:

```php
$count  = DB::table('incidencia_tiempo')
            ->where(DB::raw('ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time, created_at))'), '>', 24)
            ->count();
```

Comment: hello! could you check my post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660066/how-to-join-two-tables-with-a-pivot-table-using-laravel

Answer (score 0):

what is yoiur  mean ***time is higher than 24 hours***?

Comment: Beetween time and created at... I would like to count... if beetween the two times the hours are higher than 24 hours then add +1 to the count

Comment: mean if different ***time*** and ***created_at*** higher than 24h?

Comment: yes... I want to take the difference between time and created_at and make a count... the difference have to be higher than 24h to count

Comment: OooooooooooooooooooK

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method for Compare and Count Dates**

```
$text_count = Text::whereBetween('created_at', [$date1, $date2])->count();
```

Comment: How could I use that in my query bro?

Comment: If you meant tiempo1 count then. - $tiempo1 = Tiempo1 ::whereBetween('created_at', [$date1, $date2])->count();

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to run simple query for getting all the data like

```
$tiempo1  = DB::table('incidencia_tiempo')->get();
```

and add one loop for this query data

```
$count = 0;
foreach($tiempo1 as $time) {
  $start  = new Carbon($time->time);
  $end    = new Carbon($time->created_at);
  $hours = $start->diff($end)->format('%H');

  if ($hours > 24){
    $count++;
  }
}
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: I'm doing a count  with numbers, that's why I used ->count();... so I can't use ->get(); because I obtained all the dates, but not a count... how could I use count with this method?