# How to join two tables with a pivot table using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have these three tables:

```
tbl_lista_contactabilidad  tbl_equipo_postventaatc  users
-------------------------  -----------------------  -----
id                         id                       id
usuarios_id                asesor_id                name
```

`tbl_lista_contactabilidad.usuarios_id` should be related with `tbl_equipo_postventaatc.asesor_id`. `asesor_id` should be the "pivot" between `tbl_lista_contactabilidad.usuarios_id` and `users.id` to make the relation.

I want to make this relation so I tried to do this relation in this way (I will put only the relation of the model)

Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad (Model 1)

```
public function postventaatc(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tbl_EquipoPostventaatc','usuarios_id');

}
```

Tbl_Equipo_Postventaatc (Model 2) -> This should be the pivot model

```
public function contactabilidad(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad','usuarios_id');

}

public function user(){

return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','asesor_id');

}
```

User (Model 3)

```
public function postventaatc(){

return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tbl_Lista_Postventaatc','asesor_id');

}
```

EXAMPLE:

[image]

As you see in the image... if I relate usuarios_id with users directly I will get another name and I don't want that... I want the relation just like in the image

Comment: The thing is simple. Only look at your tables in your database model and the `Model.php` will be the same. But anyways, I think you should show us your tables from your database model or maybe the table structure to know how to be concise with our answers.

Comment: Only that I want is the relation... I don't need to show the tables for that... the relation would be the same that the query.. so with the query would be enough to make the relation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join three table by laravel eloquent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model)

Comment: No, because he didn't use a pivot table... he just joined two tables separately with another table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model

Comment: I think the link has already answer the question. You can choose to use eloquent builder relationship, or use eloquent builder `join`

Comment: @TsaiKoga My problem is that when I use this query on this function it doesn't make the relation

Comment: and  why you put datas to `$users` from `tbl_lista_contactabilidad` and don't use it?

Comment: Yes I am, i'm using tbl_lista_contactabilidad.usuarios_id to make a relation with tbl_equipo_postventaatcs.asesor_id and the table tbl_equipo_postventaatcs should make a relation with users... to make a relation between tbl_lista_contactabilidad and users

Comment: @TsaiKoga I tried to explain it better in the question

Comment: Sorry for be late... I didn't have access to my computer... I updated my question with the relation that I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot table is a structure used to join two separate models together with a single relationship. This is called a [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) in Eloquent.

From what you've described, this is not the case here. Rather, it looks like a [has-many-through](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship.

If I'm understanding correctly, your relationships should look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad extends Model {
    protected $table = 'tbl_lista_contactabilidad';
    public function postventaatc() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tbl_EquipoPostventaatc::class, 'usuarios_id');
    }
}

class Tbl_EquipoPostventaatc extends Model {
    protected $table = 'tbl_equipo_postventaatc';
    public function contactabilidad() {
        return $this->hasMany(Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad::class, 'usuarios_id');
    }
}

class User extends Model {
    public function postventaatc() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Tbl_EquipoPostventaatc::class, 'asesor_id');
    }
    public function contactabilidad() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Tbl_Lista_Contactabilidad::class, Tbl_EquipoPostventaatc::class, 'asesor_id', 'usuarios_id');
    }
}
```

Obviously this is easier for a native English speaker, but I cannot stress how much easier this would be if you were following the Laravel rules around naming your models, tables, and columns. Why does `usuarios_id` column relate to a table called `tbl_equipo_postventaatc`? Why use `asesor_id` instead of `user_id`? ‍♂️ Those names have nothing to do with each other, and make it hard to figure out what is going on.

Comment: thanks for answer... I'm getting this error when I run my code ----- Trying to get property 'name' of non-object .. You know why?  Name is from tbl User

Comment: User is not associated directly because the usuarios_id is matching with asesor_id... and I need asesor_id to know which id of User corresponds with usuarios_id

Comment: You will need to add some sample data and provide a more clear explanation of the relations here. If `usuarios_id` is the same as `asesor_id` which is the same as `users.id` then I don't see the problem?

Comment: For example... usarios_id has the number 3,   asesor_id has the number..6 and I would like to call the third Id from users...  I'm working with a lot of data.. so... If I call the third number of users with the number 3 of usuarios_id will call another name that if I call the number 6 with asesor_id... So the number 3 of usuarios_id should be relared wuth the 6 of asesor_id.. and then call the third ID of users to make the relation with usuarios_id

Comment: I'm not understanding. Please update your question with sample data.

Comment: We just need some sample entries for each table and a clear explanation of how they're related.

Comment: Sorry for be late... I didn't have access to my computer... I updated my question with the relation that I want

Comment: Answer is updated. I strongly recommend rethinking your complete lack of naming consistency.

Comment: I think that postventaatc should belongs to User, but in the same way I tried and It gave me null

Comment: Read the documentation. `User::postventaatc()` returns `belongsTo`. Opposite of that is `hasOne` or `hasMany`.